# Cant configure Spring Batch to run jobs consequently

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I use the following job launcher to launch my spring batch jobs:

```
  <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor">
      <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

and my job definition is

```
  <job id="bulkExportJob" restartable="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <description>Exports an application to pdf in a bulk operation</description>

    <step id="startExport" next="exportFileTree">
      <description>Do something to start the export</description>
      <tasklet ref="startBulkActionTasklet"/>
    </step>

    <step id="exportFileTree" next="zipFileTree">
      <description>Export the application</description>
      <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="bulkActionTargetReader" writer="bulkExportFileTreeWriter" commit-interval="1" skip-limit="100000000">
          <skippable-exception-classes>
            <!-- Exceptions are handled internally to the Writer so exception should not be treated as failures -->
            <include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
          </skippable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
      </tasklet>
      <listeners>
        <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
      </listeners>
    </step>

    <step id="zipFileTree" next="sendEmail">
      <description>Creates a zip file</description>
      <tasklet ref="bulkExportZipWriter"/>
    </step>

    <step id="sendEmail" next="finishExport">
      <description>Send notification email</description>
      <tasklet ref="bulkExportSendNotification"/>
    </step>


    <step id="finishExport">
      <description>Finalise the export</description>
      <tasklet ref="finishBulkActionTasklet"/>
    </step>

  </job>
```

My intention was to run one job at a time and queue all other incoming jobs. But from the log files I can see that all jobs run in parallel. As you can see from the the code snippets I don't have any additional code to make spring batch in parallel and yet it still does. Can you please point what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` which is running jobs async and creating new thread for each job:

> TaskExecutor implementation that fires up a new Thread for each task,
>   executing it asynchronously.
>
> Supports limiting concurrent threads through the "concurrencyLimit"
>   bean property. By default, the number of concurrent threads is
>   unlimited.
>
> NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads! Consider a
>   thread-pooling TaskExecutor implementation instead, in particular for
>   executing a large number of short-lived tasks.

As suggested if you absolutely need `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` you can set `concurrencyLimit` to 1 (with `throttle-limit="1"` property) and have 1 job at time, but then you can use default `SyncTaskExecutor` which will run jobs sequentially and when one finishes other will be run (guess based on explanation that is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `throttle-limit="1"` to the tasklet definitions. The documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html indicates it defaults to 4.